# Open JPEG file with PIL and OpenCV fails

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I have lots of images saved with no file extension.

I am trying to convert those images and do some work with PIL:

```
for img_path in list_imgs:
    with Image.open(img_path) as img:
        # more code
```

For some files this works ok but for others it shows `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError`. I tried to handle the exception by opening the file with OpenCV:

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
```

But I get the following error:

```
[ WARN:0@2.312] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_tiff.cpp (462) cv::TiffDecoder::readData OpenCV TIFF: TIFFRGBAImageOK: Sorry, requested compression method is not configured
```

If I manually changed the file extension to `.jpg` for the specific file that files, I can open it using Windows Photos or any other app, even Microsoft Paint, so I know that the file is not damaged. However, both OpenCV and PIL have problems reading said file.

How can I open the image? Are there any other parameters that can be configured? Or can it be read directly into a NumPy array and then handled to PIL?

Comment: First : ensure of format of your image. You rename file with .jpg, but are you sur that this image is in JPEG format ? According error message, it seems to be a .tiff format with compression. You can use command 'file' to ensure of format of your file. (On windows : install WSL, and then use command file in shell of WSL).
Second : it seems that you have a tiff format with an compression option that is not support by PIL or Opencv. You should have to install an extension.

Comment: You're right. It says: `TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=19, compression=JPEG (old), PhotometricIntepretation=BlackIsZero` 


What extension should I install? Thanks.

Comment: "TIFF image data" : is the most important, so .tiff extension.

Comment: Please share a file. Try [`imagecodecs.imread()`](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) or [`tifffile.imread()`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).